# Explanation of the usage of std::max in that code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, max

I am unsure whether or not I better should have posted this question on codereview.stackexchange.com. Anyway, here we go ...

Please consider the following code snippet which is a literal (I have only changed the formatting) excerpt from [here](https://github.com/ola-ct/pwned/blob/master/pwned-lib/passwordinspector.cpp) and has been printed (in stripped-down form) in the German computer magazine c't, issue 23/2019:

```
while (lo <= hi) {
  std::streamoff pos = std::streamoff((uint64_t(lo) + uint64_t(hi)) / 2);
  pos -= pos % std::streamoff(PasswordHashAndCount::size);
  pos = std::max<int64_t>(0, pos);
  phc.read(mInputFile, pos);
  ++nReads;
  if (hash > phc.hash) {
    lo = pos + std::streamoff(PasswordHashAndCount::size);
  }
  else if (hash < phc.hash) {
    hi = pos - std::streamoff(PasswordHashAndCount::size);
  }
  else {
    safe_assign(readCount, nReads);
    return phc;
  } 
}
```

Why do we need the fourth line `pos = std::max<int64_t>(0, pos);`?

From the second line, we see that `pos` is equal or greater to `0`, because it is the half of the sum of two numbers which themselves are of type `uint64_t`.

The third line can't make `pos` lower than `0`. Proof:

For simplicity, replace `pos` by `A` and `std::streamoff(PasswordHashAndCount::size)` by `B`. Then the third line reads `A -= A % B` which is equivalent to `A = A - (A % B)`, where `A` and `B` are integers, `A` being equal to or greater than `0`, and `B` being greater than `0` (because `::size` is always greater than 0).

First, if `A < B`, `A % B = A`. In this case, the third line becomes `A = A - A`, that is, `A = 0`.

Secondly, if `A == B`, `A % B` becomes `A % A` which is `0`. Therefore, the third line becomes `A = A - 0`, which is equivalent to a null operation. In other words, `A` does not change in that case; notably, it remains `0` or greater than that.

Third, if `A > B`, `A - (A % B)` is greater than `0`. This is because `A % B` is smaller than `B`, and thus, `A - (A % B)` is greater than `A - B`. The latter in turn is greater than `0`, because the condition here was `A > B`.

Of course, the three cases `A > B`, `A < B` and `A == B` are all cases which can occur. In every case, the third line assigns a new value to `A` which is `0` or positive.

Coming back to the original variable naming, that means that `pos` is always `0` or greater than that after execution of the third line.

Given that, I don't understand what the fourth line does. After all, `max(0, pos)` is always equivalent to `pos` if `pos` is `0` or positive.

What am I missing? Is there an error in the reasoning above?

Comment: If `pos` is larger than the maximum value of a `int64_t`, what value would that resulting integer be as a `int64_t`?

Comment: Unless I've missed something (again), that can't happen because `pos` is the half of an `uint64_t` (see second line). I believe that the full code of the project doesn't cleanly handle such type of errors anyway :-), probably because the author assumes that so large files won't be fed to the software (~ 9 Exabyte) ...

Comment: its the mean of two unsigneds which can exceed the range of signed int.

Comment: Could you please give an example? After all, the maximum `uint16_t` is `65535`, and `65535 / 2` is `32767`, which is exactly the maximum `int16_t`. It's the same with `uint32_t` (maximum `4294967295`, and `4294967295 / 2 = 2147483647`, and the latter is exactly the maximum `int32_t`). Anything different with the 64-bit types?

Comment: you keep saying that is is half of an unsigned, but it is `(lo + hi) /2`, and max of unsigned exceeds max of signed: https://godbolt.org/z/jW5KrPY51

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. But I still don't get it. I guess that the sum `(lo + hi)` in every case is a `uint64_t` if `lo` and `hi` are of that type. Is this correct, or is there an implicit type cast to `int128_t` when adding those numbers? If the latter is the case, I understand the problem. But if there is no implicit type cast, the sum of two `uint64_t` is an `uint64_t` as well, and if I (integer-)divide that sum by 2, the result will fit into an `int64_t`.

Comment: well yes (https://godbolt.org/z/1zWv51h8W) thats the detail I also dont get. If `pos` would not fit in a `int64_t` then I think `std::max<int64_t>(0,pos);` would be UB.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Not UB. Well defined since C++20, implementation defined before that (practically same as after C++20 on 2's complement systems, which is practically every system that one would encounter).

Comment: @eerorika ok no UB, but anyhow I dont see how that could happen ( (unit64_t + uint64_t)/2 > int64_t)

Comment: if nothing else makes sense I would consider the possibility that the line is just to document that `0 < pos < max_int64_t`. Its much better than a comment, because comments can be wrong

Comment: anyhow, I think the best would be to ask the author. Eventually only they know why they put that line.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Just wanted finally to thank you for all your comments and help - will now study eerorika's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider what exactly it does:

> ```
> std::streamoff pos = std::streamoff((uint64_t(lo) + uint64_t(hi)) / 2);
> pos = std::max<int64_t>(0, pos);
> ```

`std::streamoff` is some implementation defined signed integer type. Let's consider a case where it is a 64 bit type or smaller: The value of `pos` will not be changed by the conversion to `int64_t` because the type is wider, nor when converting back in the assignment because the original value must have been representable.

Let's consider a case where `std::streamoff` is a 128 bit type or wider: The value comes from `(uint64_t(lo) + uint64_t(hi)) / 2` which cannot exceed maximum of `int64_t`. Thus, the value cannot be changed by the conversion in this case either.

Thus, the use of `int64_t` has no effect in any case.

> The third line can't make pow lower than 0
>
> Is there an error in the reasoning above?

I cannot find any error.

> Given that, I don't understand what the fourth line does.

The line has no effect at on the behaviour of the program at all. The program would have equivalent behaviour if the line was written:

```
;
```

---

Besides, on most systems that you find on desktop or server, `std::streamoff` and `int64_t` have the same number of bits.

Comment: Accepted and +1; thank you very much for the clear explanation. I'm glad that the question wasn't as silly as I initially feared and that this code actually does not do anything. Perhaps I'll treat myself to the fun and ask the author why he inserted that line. I guess opening an issue on Github just to ask this wouldn't be appropriate :-), so I'll email him. By the way, since I'm not in C++, I was surprised to read that the size of `std::streamoff` is implementation dependent, so thanks for that detail as well.